Left padding on right positioning legend in react-chartjs-2 line chart
I am using react-chartjs-2 line chart and assign legend position to right side but graph and legend does not containing the space. I want to provide left padding to my legend which create the space between chart and legend. Please provide any suggestion or solution on it.

I want to provide padding or margin between graph and legend.
